# AdWords wildly misreporting number of clicks - 3rd party tracking page missing 50% of clicks

Tags: php, mysql, google-ads-api

I manage AdWords accounts for a few clients. I use my own custom tracking link that I place in the AdWords destination URL box for my client's ads (example: http://www.mywebsite.com/track.php?id=1234567890 ).

This link leads to a simple PHP page that records the IP Address, places a cookie on the remote machine, and saves everything to a mysql database. It then forwards the user to the client's landing page.

Problem is, AdWords will report 10 clicks, but my PHP tracking page is only reporting 5. Why is my tracking page missing so many clicks?

-My sever up-time has been 100% in the past 30 days.

-My server has error reporting enabled. No errors logged.

-My code:

```
<?php

//determine which client/campaign this belongs to by reading get id from URL
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $tracker_id = $_GET['id'];
} else {
   exit('Sorry, that ID is invalid.');
}

//if referrer is same page we just forwarded to, prevent rest of code from running to prevent redirect loop:
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'http://www.clientshomepage.com') {
        //stop running script and send user back to where they originally came from:
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.history.go(-1);</script>';
        exit();
    }   
} 

//check to see if remote machine already has cookie set:
if (!isset($_COOKIE[$tracker_id])) {
    //create tracking id:
    $cookie_id = mt_rand(100000000, 999999999); 
    //insert unique ID into cookie and place on remote machine:
    setcookie($tracker_id, $cookie_id, time() + (86400 * 365), "/");
} else {
    $cookie_id = $_COOKIE[$tracker_id];
}

//log the IP address of the person clicking:
if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
    $remote_addr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
} else {
    $remote_addr = '';
}

//include pdo/mysql credentials file:
require('pdo.php');

//insert collected data about this click into the database:
try {


    $sql = "INSERT INTO mytable_name (tracker_id, cookie_id, remote_addr, click_time) 
            VALUES (:tracker_id, :cookie_id, INET_ATON(:remote_addr), :click_time)";

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->execute( 
            array( 
            ':tracker_id'               => $tracker_id,
            ':cookie_id'                => $cookie_id,
            ':remote_addr'              => $remote_addr,
            ':click_time'               => time()
            ) 
        );

    $stmt = null;   

} catch (PDOException $err) {
    exit('Error Number: ' . $err->getCode() . '<br>' . 'Sorry, there was a database error. Please notify technical support.');
}

//forward user to landing page:
echo '<script>window.location = "http://www.clientslandingpage.com"</script>';


//in case redirect fails due to disabled javascript, redirect user old school style:
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=http://www.clientslandingpage.com"/>';

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The page that inserts to the db could be getting cached.  So the meta redirect to adwords is working because the browser cached it, but your server is not being hit so it can't save to the db.  You can try adding some no-cache headers like:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

(This assumes that what you're missing is multiple clicks from same user.)

Comment: Hmmm...interesting idea and something I never considered. I just looked at the database and I have a single IP address (67.168.102.122) that was reported clicking my ad three times in one 24 hour period. So I assume this means caching is not the issue?